# JPQL - avoid using join

Tags: sql, database, join, jpql

i have 3 tables: action, department, employee

```
action (
  id
  employee_id
  name
)

employee(
  id
  department_id
)

department (
  id
  name
)
```

- action.employee_id can be null

i'm using the following query:

```
select a.id, a.name, d.name from action a, employee e, department d where         a.employee_id=e.id and e.department_id=d.id
```

but in the case of an action without employee_id i don't get those rows in the result

is there a way to overcome this without using left join?

---

tried so far (didn't work):

```
select a.id, a.name, d.name from action a, employee e, department d where         (a.employee_id=e.id and e.department_id=d.id) or a.employee_id is null
```

Comment: why didn't it work? what output do you see?

Comment: it returned all the combinations of actions and department names (for the rows that have no `employee_id`). if i have x actions and in all of them the `employee_id` is null and y departments it returned x*y results instead of just x results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the whole point of JPA: having objects associated with other objects directly, rather than objects holding IDs of other objects.

You should have an Action entity with a ManyToOne association to an Employee entity, which would have a ManyToOne association to a Department entity. You should NOT have an employeeId field in Action. And you should NOT have a departmentId field in Employee.

This would allow you, for example, to get the department name of an action by simply calling

```
action.getEmployee().getDepartment().getName()
```

And you would be able to use left joins in your query, which would become

```
select a.id, a.name, d.name
from Action a
left join a.employee e
left join e.department d
```

and would give you the expected result

Comment: i know this is the correct way to use JPA but from what i understand it also leads to loading much larger objects to the cache and i wanted to avoid that. there are no important connections with the actions table in the core business logic so i'm fine with a one-time solution.
i thought of a query much like the one you posted but i dont want to create these connections if i'm not gonna use them widely - that's y i'm trying to avoid using join

Comment: I think that in order to prevent that you can use (fetch = FetchType.LAZY)

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. Every association can be marked as lazy-loaded. You're fighting the tool because you don't adopt its way of doing. Don't be surprised to bump into walls. You best option if you want to do it your way is to use a native SQL query with left joins.